# How can I show a histogram that was computed server side?

Tags: highcharts

I compute a histogram server-side using numpy which gives the histogram data in the arrays `bins` and `edges`. How can I show this in highcharts so that the tick-labels showing edges are in-between the columns showing bins? The histogram graph does not work since it computes the histogram on the client side.

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of the data that you have generated?

Comment: Yes, I recreated the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/41pqbc9L/

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is, your demo doesn't include the histogram series at all. It could be added in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7a2m1fj0/

Comment: Sorry, I see that this is confusing. graph_data is the server-side computed histogram. But the columns a really narrow, basically they should be as wide as the x_data intervals of graph_data.

Comment: I see. If you want to use your own data, you should use the variwide series rather than the column. It allows setting the z (could be treated as a width) value. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4az65rmy/